# Best way to approach daily push notifications?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I want to implement push notifications within my iPhone app, it's kind of a word of the day notification and I want to have it so that each day at a given time, a notification is pushed to every one of my users. I anticipate the app will be used by around 8000 people - what is the recommended way to do this without overloading a server and costing something astronomical?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

http://urbanairship.com/ is your friend (I'm a user, but have no stake or investment with them). 1 Million free Pushes per month—which should be more than adequate for you. Just tie into their API if you want to automate it, or use their website for manual send.

https://go.urbanairship.com/accounts/register/